# Using class name I am firing a click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

Using class name I am firing a click event in jquery. Class names are added to different types of controls, is there  any way to check type of control it is been fired?
jquery event

```
$(".ClassName").live("click", function (e) {
    //Here I want type of controller which fires this event

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you even identify the controls? you didn't even mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ClassName").live("click", function (e) {

alert(this.nodeName);

});
```